# Changing LUKS passwords noninteractively?

Tags: linux, luks

I'm kickstarting hosts to use LUKS - and as part of that, I've got a rather basic 'default' password in the kickstart file.

We 'finish' new builds via ansible, and so as part of this - I'd like to change the default luks password to something a little more robust (and managed via Ansible).

What I can't figure out though, is how I can use cryptsetup (or something else?) non-interactively to update the password.

I do want to *keep* using a password (and not a key file) - we're starting to deploy Clevis/Tang to do Network Bound Disk Encryption on root drives, and want to retain the password-to-boot option.

It seems

```
echo "oldpassphrase
newpassphrase" | cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2
```

Might do the trick, but it feels like a messy option?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to *create* a LUKS container non-interactively by using standard input as the key file: `echo -n "mypassword" cryptsetup luksFormat --key-file - dev/sda2`

But it's not possible to change the password non-interactively *and* without using key files because:

1. `cryptsetup` does not accept passwords in the command line; It only accepts them from files and interactively; Probably to prevent leaking the password into your shell's history.
2. Although you can use standard input as a key file, to add or change passwords you need to provide an existing password along with the new one; That's two inputs and there's only one standard input.

### Option 1 - Use named pipes

Technically this requires a file, but the file is a named pipe, not a key file:

```
mkpipe fifo
echo -n "oldpass" | cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-file - test.img fifo &
echo -m "newpass" > fifo
```

The first command creates the named pipe, the second uses stdin to provide the original password and reads the new password from the pipe. This second command blocks, so the `&` puts it in the background. The third command writes the new password into the pipe, which allows cryptsetup to unblock and proceed.

### Option 2 - Using the cryptsetup API

Cryptsetup is not only a utility, but also a library (libcryptsetup). You can use a function like [crypt_keyslot_add_by_passphrase()](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/lib/libcryptsetup.h#L760) in your own code to add a new password. This particular function accepts the existing and new password as `char *` (a string).

Answer (score 0):

```
ct=$(cat /etc/crypttab)   
[[ $ct =~ ((sda[0-9])_crypt[[:blank:]]) ]] || _fail Could not find crypted partition  
part="/dev/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo Partition is $part

(echo "$existingPW"; echo "$newPW"; echo "$newPW") | cryptsetup luksAddKey $part
```

... takes a few seconds to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you create a new volume as follows:

```
echo -n pass0 | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda2 -
```

So the password in keyslot #0 is "pass0".

Next, you want to set the password in keyslot #1 to "pass1":

```
echo -n "pass0pass1" | cryptsetup luksAddKey --key-file /dev/stdin --keyfile-size 5 --key-slot 1 /dev/sda2 /dev/stdin
```

The length of the first password, "pass0", is 5 characters, and that's why you specify "--keyfile-size 5".